# Complex number notation

Tags: c#, math, notation, complex-numbers

My DotNET application has a limited scripting language build in (modelled loosely on VBScript) mainly for post-processing numbers, points and vectors. I've just added support for complex numbers, but I'm struggling with the notation.

I don't want to use the A + Bi notation, since it is not a clear division if A or B are defined as equations already:

31 * 5 + 6 + -5i

This could be interpreted as:

A = 31 * 5 + 6
B = -5i

and:

A = 31 * 5
B = 6 + -5i

None of the programming languages I know have native support for complex numbers. I'm thinking  something like the following might work, but I'd appreciate any input on this:

{31 * 5} + {6 + -5}i

complex(31 * 5, 6 + -5)

r{31 * 5} i{6 + -5}

Comment: Would polar coordinates be better than rectangular coordinates?  Just another way to express those kinds of numbers.

Comment: @JB, Don't know. Could be. I can certainly add another syntax that allows you to define a complex number by angle+distance. The default notation uses a real and an imaginary component though.

Comment: C has native complex numbers since C99. So has Fortran.

Comment: @lhf, how do you define a complex number in C or Fortran?

Comment: must not be seeing it, because I read 31 * 5 + 6 + -5i as 161 - 5i which without any parentheses in the equation is the (fairly) standard way to interpret it given pretty well all languages operator precedence. If you are seeing it as 155 * (6 - 5i) then you are screwing around with peoples perceptions of operator precedence

Comment: @David Rutten, see http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html and http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/802-5662/6i9dg8itg?a=view

Comment: BTW, there's a library for complex numbers for Lua. See http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lcomplex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using explicit multiplication in your examples (i.e. you require A * B, rather than A B ).

In that case why not simply use the i suffix directly following the value as in

```
 myComplex = 12 + 6i
   or
 myOtherComplex = 12/7 + (6 * pi)i
```

Then you may need to decide about i or j,  I've seen both...

This i-suffix trick is not unlike the scientific notication and is e   (3.1415e7 for example)

**Edit** (following David's comments)

The format above can become confusing, depending on the audience, one way to clarify this may be to **only allow for imaginary *literals***, and to include these into **a complex notation derived from your existing vector notation**.  When imaginary numbers or complex number require an expression to designate them, the syntax would require the **explicit "function-looking" syntax** such as  Imaginary(i) and Complex(r, i).

**Parsing rules**:

- Any number (signed or unsigned, integer or decimal, or even exp. notation number) directly followed by the suffix i is a imaginary number:  -7i or 1.23i or 5.76e4i  but not 12 i (no space allowed between number and suffix)
- a two values vector with the first one real and the 2nd imaginary is a complex:  (1, 7i) or even (7, 0i)
- Imaginary(i) format is used when "i" value is an expression. i is expressed without the i suffix which is implied by the method call syntax.
- Complex(r,i) format is used when either "r" or "i" params is/are an expression, and also whenever we wish to avoid ambiguity.

**In short**:

- (7, 1i) ,  (0, -3.1415i), (13, 0i), Complex(13, 0) or Complex(7x+3, sin(y)+2) are all complex numbers
- 6i,  -1.234e5i, Imaginary(1.234) or Imaginary(sqrt(19x+5y))  are all imaginary numbers
- (12, 23, 34) is a vector in R^3
- (12i, -2i) in a vector in I^2  (not a complex number, since the first element is not real)
- ((0,0i), (1,-9.2i), (12, 0i))  or ((0, 21i), Complex(12,3), (44, -55i)) are vectors in C^3

That's seems consistent and simple enough, but then again, only the true end-users can tell.

Comment: @mjv, interesting idea. It certainly makes for a very flexible notation. However I fear it becomes too easy to make syntactic mistakes this way. It will confuse people.

Comment: @David R: see my 2nd approach...  Just a suggestion, of course, you know your users more than I...

Answer (score 2):

If your desire is to simply differentiate the real from the imaginary component for a complex number, I'd do one of the following.

- Enclose the number with some form of parentheses to ensure it's treated as a unit. For example, 6+5i becomes {6,5} or {6,5i} for extra readability.
- Introduce a marker to separate the parts, similar to the exponent in 6.022e23. For example, 6+5i becomes 6i5. You'd still need parentheses to specify formulae for this one, such as 6 + (b/2)i becoming 6i(b/2), not the confusing 6ib/2 (which could also be read as (6ib)/2) and unfortunately you lose the use of i as a variable.

Either of those would be simple to process even with a simple parser and they're close enough to the mathematical notation so as not to confuse. I prefer the first since it seems more explicit to me and uses symbols that are unlikely to confuse.

Comment: @Pax, thanks. I think the bracket approach will work best. I won't use the "i" suffix, since it would be too confusing in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Do your users have a specific notation they use? Could you pick one as close to theirs as possible? In my case I'd use a + bi so I'd say {31 * 5} + {6 + -5}i however, if they used to the functional form then I suggest complex(31 * 5, 6 + -5).

Since you're using .net you might want to use the DLR to give your scripting [python](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython) or [ruby](http://www.ironruby.net/) syntax?

Comment: Complex numbers weren't available until now, so there is no syntax yet. Points and Vectors are written as {x, y, z}. Complex numbers could be {a, b}, which is nice and short, but unfortunately not very self-documenting. "complex(,)" is good though.

I'm writing in DotNET, but I wrote the interpreter for the scripting language myself. I needed a whole lot of special operators (factorial, square, cross-product, dot-product, remap-plane etc. etc.) Also, since most of my users come from a VB background I wanted something which looks like regular VBScript until you use the special features.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about how the users currently use complex numbers generally (not in your app).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the languages I can find that have a complex number builtin type (such as Python and Lisp) use something like:

```
c{r, i}
```